# Update each row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have a table with some value columns, a formula, and a result column.

```
|rownum|value1|value2|value3|formula             |result|
|------|------|------|------|--------------------|------|
|1     |11    |30    |8     |value1/value2*value3|      |
|2     |43    |0     |93    |value1-value2+value3|      |
```

I want to populate the `result` column with the result of the formula.

Currently I'm doing that with this query:

```
DECLARE @v_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @v_Sql = CAST ((SELECT
           ' UPDATE [table] ' +
            ' SET [result] = ' + table.[formula] +
            ' WHERE [rownum] = ' + CAST(table.[rownum] as nvarchar(255)) +
            ';'
          FROM [table]
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR (MAX))

EXEC (@v_Sql)
```

The problem is that this takes a very long time. The # rows in the table will be 5 - 10 million.

Is there any way to speed this up? Of alternative approaches to this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It's better place for working code that you want to speed up.

Comment: is formula act a computed column ?

Comment: You need to look for bottlenecks in your `update`. Do you have any triggers, indexes or FK? What kind of isolation are you using? Look at a query plan as well.

Comment: it seems you will use this result column on future , you didnt use triggers or another thigs to run that formula while data was inserting , so you may do it at one query parsing the formula and decode it from string to real processes. I will try a query

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The likely problem though is that the result column should have already contained the result of the function. Don't know if this is a one-time update series you want to run. If not, you should be initialising the result column as soon as the formula column changes or upon inserts.

Comment: @TT. how would I do that? the formula is saved in a varchar field. I see no other way then to create the update statement using the contents of the field and then executing it.

Comment: @tv87 You could create an `AFTER INSERT/UPDATE TRIGGER` which reevaluates the formula and puts the result in the result column. That way you do not have to evaluate the whole table each time, just for the rows that were inserted or updated. I don't think you update/insert 5/10 million rows each time.

Comment: @tv87 check my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it quicker bulk updating by formula types? Index needed on [formula] also:

```
DECLARE @v_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @v_Sql = CAST ((SELECT
           ' UPDATE [table] ' +
            ' SET [result] = ' + [table].[formula] +
            ' WHERE [formula] = ''' + [table].[formula] + ''';'
          FROM [table]
          group by [table].[formula]
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR (MAX))
exec(@v_Sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming operator order rules and covering only your simple formula example:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET  [result] = case replace(replace(replace([formula],'value1', ''), 'Value2', ''), 'Value3', '')
        when '++' then [value1] + [value2] + [Value3]
        when '+-' then [value1] + [value2] - [Value3]
        when '+*' then [value1] + [value2] * [Value3]
        when '+/' then [value1] + [value2] / [Value3]
        when '-+' then [value1] - [value2] + [Value3]
        when '--' then [value1] - [value2] - [Value3]
        when '-*' then [value1] - [value2] * [Value3]
        when '-/' then [value1] - [value2] / [Value3]
        when '*+' then [value1] * [value2] + [Value3]
        when '*-' then [value1] * [value2] - [Value3]
        when '**' then [value1] * [value2] * [Value3]
        when '*/' then [value1] * [value2] / [Value3]
        when '/+' then [value1] / [value2] + [Value3]
        when '/-' then [value1] / [value2] - [Value3]
        when '/*' then [value1] / [value2] * [Value3]
        when '//' then [value1] / [value2] / [Value3]
        end
from [Table]
```

Comment: thanks, but the way I presented the problem is very simplified. There are actually 7 fields. The formula consists of 1 or more of those fields and can be constructed in any fashion. There are no limitations to the structure of the formula other than that it has to be mathematically correct.

Comment: @tv87  I have added another answer that could help.

Answer (score 1):

Two simple things that come to mind:

1. Make sure there is an index on `rownum` column if you are updating each row individually.
2. If there are only few different formulas you can update all rows with the same formula in one `UPDATE` instead of updating each row individually. In this case an index on `formula` column would help.

Comment: Hi, I added an index on the rownum column which sped up the query. Unfortunately it's still far to slow.
The number of different formulas used is limited and depends on a dimension linked to this table. So maybe for 1 million lines there are 100 unique formulas to be applied.
I'll try to move the formulas to this dimension table and retrieve it from there to limit the amount of update statements that have to be executed.

Comment: @tv87, it is definitely faster to run `UPDATE` 100 times, than 1,000,000 times. Especially when the total number of updated rows is the same. It should be almost 10,000 times faster. Having index on `formula` column is important, though.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the trigger option, but for now, updating in chunks will have less impact.

`TOP(5000)` will update just 5000 rows each time `WHERE [result] is null OR [result]=''`

`GO 20000` will execute this query 20000 times (10 million rows)  It will continue to execute until returns 0 records for the UPDATE statement.

```
DECLARE @v_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @v_Sql = CAST ((SELECT
           ' UPDATE TOP (5000) [table] ' +
            ' SET [result] = ' + [table].[formula] +
            ' WHERE [formula] = ''' + [table].[formula] + '''
             AND ([result] is null OR [result]='');'
          FROM [table]
          group by [table].[formula]
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR (MAX))
exec(@v_Sql)

    GO 20000
```

After this, create the trigger

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies and ideas. In the end the issue was solved by saving the formula in the dimension instead of the fact table.
This generates 1 update statement for each line in the dimension and applies it to all relevant fact lines with a where clause, as opposed to 1 update statement for each fact line.
The process time went down from > 1,5 hours to less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

I've just create table with 5 million rows. With table structure as:

```
rn  t1  t2  t3  formula
1   80  23  93  t1 / t2 * t3
2   80  87  30  t1 / t2 * t3
3   92  83  63  t1 / t2 * t3
4   68  19  36  t1 / t2 * t3
5   65  63  10  t1 / t2 * t3
```

If you sure, that all you formulas are valid, and you will not have division by zero for example, or data type overflow, in this case you can make your own eval() function in SQL server.

I created my own function for 3 values in formula with signs like:
'+', '-', '*', '/'.

The function code is:

```
use db_test;
go

alter function dbo.eval(@a varchar(max))
returns float
as
begin
    set @a = replace(@a, ' ', '');

    declare @pos1 int = PATINDEX('%[+/*-]%', @a);
    declare @t1 float = cast(substring(@a, 1, @pos1 - 1) as float);
    declare @sign1 char(1) = substring(@a, @pos1, 1);
    set @a = substring(@a, @pos1 + 1, len(@a) - @pos1);

    declare @pos2 int = PATINDEX('%[+/*-]%', @a);
    declare @t2 float = cast(substring(@a, 1, @pos2 - 1) as float);
    declare @sign2 char(1) = substring(@a, @pos2, 1);
    set @a = substring(@a, @pos2 + 1, len(@a) - @pos2);

    declare @t3 float = cast(@a as float);

    set @t1 = (
        case @sign1
            when '+' then @t1 + @t2
            when '-' then @t1 - @t2
            when '*' then @t1 * @t2
            when '/' then @t1 / @t2
        end 
    );

    set @t1 = (
        case @sign2
            when '+' then @t1 + @t3
            when '-' then @t1 - @t3
            when '*' then @t1 * @t3
            when '/' then @t1 / @t3
        end 
    );

    return @t1;
end;
```

And it works on next data:

```
select dbo.eval('7.6*11.3/4.5') as eval, 7.6*11.3/4.5 as sqlServerCalc;

eval                 sqlServerCalc
19,0844444444444     19.084444
```

After that you can replace values in your formula by column values and calculate it:

```
with cte as (
    select rn, t1, t2, t3, formula, 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(formula, 't1', cast(t1 as varchar(max))), 't2', cast(t2 as varchar(max))), 't3', cast(t3 as varchar(max))) as calc
    from db_test.dbo.loop
)
select rn, t1, t2, t3, formula, db_test.dbo.eval(calc) as result
into db_test.dbo.loop2
from cte;
```

Time is okay for me, it takes 3 minutes on my Sql Server 2016 and makes good results:

```
select top 5 *
from db_test.dbo.loop2;
rn  t1  t2  t3  formula         result
1   80  23  93  t1 / t2 * t3    323,478260869565
2   80  87  30  t1 / t2 * t3    27,5862068965517
3   92  83  63  t1 / t2 * t3    69,8313253012048
4   68  19  36  t1 / t2 * t3    128,842105263158
5   65  63  10  t1 / t2 * t3    10,3174603174603
```

If you have a list of all the operations that are applicable in the formula, you can write a common function for several variables. But, if there is something more complicated in the formula, then CLR should be used.